# Using css selectors as inputs for javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, listener

So far I'm using different buttons for different transitions (each one with individual function) on one DOM element :

```
onButtonClickUp = function(){
    document.querySelector('.cube-rot').style.transform="rotateY(90deg)"
    };
onButtonClickDown = function(){
    document.querySelector('.cube-rot').style.transform="rotateY(-90deg)"
};
onButtonClickRight = function(){
    document.querySelector('.cube-rot').style.transform="rotateX(90deg)"
};
onButtonClickLeft = function(){
    document.querySelector('.cube-rot').style.transform="rotateX(-90deg)"
};
document.querySelector('.show-up').addEventListener( 'click', onButtonClickUp, false);
document.querySelector('.show-down').addEventListener( 'click', onButtonClickDown, false);
document.querySelector('.show-left').addEventListener( 'click', onButtonClickLeft, false);
document.querySelector('.show-right').addEventListener( 'click', onButtonClickRight, false);
```

I'm firing everything off on DomContentLoaded and it's working,
but I'd like to combine the functions into one with different cases;

---

this is what I've tried

```
 function onButtonClick(rot){
    //rot = rUp || rDown|| rLeft ||rRight ;
    if(rot == 'rUp'){rot = "rotateY(90deg)";}
    else if (rot == 'rDown'){ rot = "rotateY(90deg)"}
    else if (rot == 'rLeft'){ rot = "rotateX(90deg)"}
    else if(rot == 'rRight' ){ rot = "rotateX(-90deg)"};

    cubeRot.style.transform=rot
    };


 document.querySelector('.show-up').addEventListener( 'click', onButtonClick('rUp'), false);
 document.querySelector('.show-down').addEventListener( 'click', onButtonClick('rDown'), false);
 document.querySelector('.show-right').addEventListener( 'click', onButtonClick('rRight'), false);
 document.querySelector('.show-left').addEventListener( 'click', onButtonClick('rLeft'), false);
```

it doesn't work, adding different EventListners resolves in the last overriding previous..
what's the most convenient way to do this?

Comment: You can't use `onButtonClick('rUp')` in `addEventListener`. This executes the function directly when it's parsed. Change to `onButtonClick.bind(null, 'rUp')`,

Comment: `cubeRot.style.transform=rot` I think cubeRot is not defined, sholdn't it be `document.querySelector('.cube-rot').style.transform=rot` ?

Comment: Add some data to your _HTML_ and you can make the function much more generic, e.g. `<button class="show-up" data-axis="Y" data-deg="90" />` then you can simply read off `this` or `event.target` in the handler

Comment: @Goten It's defined ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are calling `onButtonClick()` when you do your event binding, it needs to return a function.

```
function onButtonClick(rot){
    return function(e) {
        //rot = rUp || rDown|| rLeft ||rRight ;
        if(rot == 'rUp'){rot = "rotateY(90deg)";}
        else if (rot == 'rDown'){ rot = "rotateY(-90deg)"}
        else if (rot == 'rLeft'){ rot = "rotateX(90deg)"}
        else if(rot == 'rRight' ){ rot = "rotateX(-90deg)"};

        cubeRot.style.transform=rot;
    };
}
```

Alternatively, leave the function as is and use `.bind()`:

```
document.querySelector('.show-up').addEventListener('click', onButtonClick.bind(null, 'rUp'), false);
document.querySelector('.show-down').addEventListener('click', onButtonClick.bind(null, 'rDown'), false);
document.querySelector('.show-right').addEventListener('click', onButtonClick.bind(null, 'rRight'), false);
document.querySelector('.show-left').addEventListener('click', onButtonClick.bind(null, 'rLeft'), false);
```

The above solutions should get you unblocked.  But, there are some more code improvements you could consider.

Instead of that long `if .. else if` block, you could store the value in an object and look up the value by a key:

```
var rotations = {
    rUp: "rotateY(90deg)",
    rDown: "rotateY(-90deg)",
    rLeft: "rotateX(90deg)",
    rRight: "rotateX(-90deg)"
};
function onButtonClick(rot) {
    cubeRot.style.transform = rotations[rot];
}
```

Your event handler has access to the clicked element via `this`.  You don't need to pass a `rot` argument, you can just look at `this.className`:

```
var rotations = {
    up: "rotateY(90deg)",
    down: "rotateY(-90deg)",
    left: "rotateX(90deg)",
    right: "rotateX(-90deg)"
};
function onButtonClick(e) {
    var rot = this.className.slice(5);
    cubeRot.style.transform = rotations[rot];
}
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[class^='show-']")).forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick, false);
});
```

Comment: I really like the last solution. It's minimalistic and pure JavaScript.

Comment: could you explain why you put that `^` caret to get the selector ?

Comment: The caret is part of the [attribute starts with selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) which takes the form `[attributename^='startvalue']`. In my code above, it selects all elements whose `class` attribute starts with `'show-'`, like `'show-up'`. It can be a useful trick, but is a little fragile. For example, the selector would stop working if you added a class to your element so that your attribute became `class="button show-up"`. To then get it to work again, you would have to change your html to `class="show-up button"`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your buttons are plain HTML buttons with no innerHTML you can do this

```
<input type="button" action-type="rUp" value="Show up" class="show-up" />
```

This adds an attribute to the input with the desired action variable.

```js
function onButtonClick(e){
    var rot = e.target.getAttribute("action-type");
    if(rot == 'rUp'){rot = "rotateY(90deg)";}
    else if (rot == 'rDown'){ rot = "rotateY(90deg)"}
    else if (rot == 'rLeft'){ rot = "rotateX(90deg)"}
    else if(rot == 'rRight' ){ rot = "rotateX(-90deg)"};

    cubeRot.style.transform=rot;
    };


 document.querySelector('.show-up').addEventListener( 'click', onButtonClick, false);
 document.querySelector('.show-down').addEventListener( 'click', onButtonClick, false);
 document.querySelector('.show-right').addEventListener( 'click', onButtonClick, false);
 document.querySelector('.show-left').addEventListener( 'click', onButtonClick, false);
```

When the event is fired `e.target` refers to the element that fired the event (the button). `rot` stores the attribute `action-type`. Based upon `rot` the correct action will be applied. The advantage is that this doesn't require new functions to be created or functions to be wrapped in a bind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the this object to reference the button that's triggering the event:

```
  var onButtonClick = function () {
    var button = this;
    document.querySelector('.dir').innerHTML = button.name;
    switch(button.name) {
       case 'up': alert('up'); break;
       case 'down': alert('down'); break;
       case 'left': alert('left'); break;
       case 'right': alert('right'); break;
     }
  };

  document.querySelector('.show-up').addEventListener('click', onButtonClick, false);
  document.querySelector('.show-down').addEventListener('click', onButtonClick, false);
  document.querySelector('.show-left').addEventListener('click', onButtonClick, false);
  document.querySelector('.show-right').addEventListener('click', onButtonClick, false);
```

Check this plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/MJzMffnDZJripzXkiZzc

Happy coding!